# Best video codec for filmed powerpoint presentation

Tags: video, video-conversion, video-codecs

I have some presentations that are filmed. The audio is the presenter and the video is all the Powerpoint slides (size 1024x768, video codec H264, audio codec AAC).

I would like to reduce their final file size since a 1 hour presentation is about 800 MB. Most of it is the video part which as I said is mostly powerpoint slides that don't change much over a matter of several seconds.

Which codec would be better suited to encode this images and reduce the size of the end file?

Answer (score 4):

The *best* codec is difficult to say, since the H264 is a lossy codec, and you don't say how much of a reduction in quality you are willing to tolerate.

On the other hand, if the video is just images of the slides, you might consider re-coding this as a *video podcast*. It has all the features for cycling thru a bunch of still images while an audio track is playing, and only taking the minimum space needed to hold everything.

Answer (score 0):

Better still, have users install the FREE [power point viewer](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13) you can download from Microsoft.  Then you just send your power point file, which should be significantly smaller.  If they're an Ubuntu user [Liber office](http://www.libreoffice.org) will display it.  For the Mac guys Keynote is the only way to go.  You can D/L a free 30 day trial of [iWork](http://www.apple.com/iwork/).

Comment: The idea is not the powerpoint file - everybody has Office available - it's the "soundtrack" of the presenter while a specific slide is shown. If I could synchronize the PPT with the audio that would be great, otherwise the users will wonder which slide the presenter is talking about.